# How to create a tooltip using bootstrap 3 and javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a game and I want to create tooltip for items, there is alot of them and player can possibly store 100 or more items. I want each of them to display stats in tooltip, without any delay when hovering. I am using basic html data-toogle I believe or maybe its part of bootstrap I dont know.

```
html += '<img src="images/items/' + playerInventory[i].subType + "/"  + 
playerInventory[i].image + '.png" "data-toggle=" "tooltip" title="'
html += "You will gain:"
html += '\n'
html += "Item Type: " + playerInventory[i].subType + '\n'
    if (playerInventory[i].minDamage > 0 && playerInventory[i].maxDamage > 0) {
html += "Min Damage: " + (playerInventory[i].minDamage - itemStat.minDamage) + '\n'
html+= "Max Damage: " + (playerInventory[i].maxDamage - itemStat.maxDamage) + '\n'
            }
```

The problem is that I want to change the way this pop up window appear, I want to remove delay, change colors/font etc. I am using javascript only and so far I found most if not all answer in jquery which does not help me at all.

Comment: you will need to edit the css of the resulting element overriding the default bootstrap css

Comment: Hey, I don't understand :/ What is default bootstrap css?  is "title" or "tooltip" part of bootstrap css?

Comment: the style of the tooltip is from the bootstrap css file if you want to change the style you have two options change the bootstrap css file or create your own and overide the default bootstrap file

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer then :) I will work on that.